# How to realize a table with a specific elements subset

Tags: python, string, list, center

I have to sketch out the periodic table with ten elements through a list like the following one:

```
pt = [(1,"Hydrogen","H",1), (2,"Helium","He",4), ...].
```

As follows, the widths of the corresponding columns in the table and to the required alignment

```
 (3 right + 20 left + 6 center + 10 right).
```

The final results I should obtain look like this.

[image]

I have tried to create through the `package tabulate`, following this procedure

```
pt = [(1,"Hydrogen","H",1.008), (2,"Helium","He",4.0026), (3, "Lithium", "Li", 6.94), (4, "Beryllium", "Be", 9.0122),
      (5, "Boron", "B", 10.81), (6, "Carbon", "C", 12.011), (7, "Nitrogen", "N", 14.007), (8, "Oxygen", "O", 15.999),
      (9, "Fluorine", "F", 18.998), (10, "Neon", "Ne", 20.180)]
head = ["No.", "Name", "Symbol", "Weight"]
print(tabulate(pt, headers=head, tablefmt="grid"))
```

The results is nice

[image]

but since I have to respect the width dimensions, as described above, I do not how to include them in the code. I was suggested to create the first three lines manually but lines with chemical elements should be created in the `'for' loop (for an item in pt:)`. Use methods for strings `(rjust, center, ljust)`.

Is there anyone that knows how to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Were did you got stuck? SO isn't a free coding service. Please read [ask] and [tour] (once again).

Comment: Are you asking what `(3 right + 20 left + 6 center + 10 right)` means?

Comment: @0stone0 Exactly

Comment: My guess: First col: 3 width, align right -- Second col: 20 width, align left -- etc...

Comment: @0stone0 actually I am not able how to start

Comment: Thanks but even with this in hand I ignore how to proceed

Comment: Well thats to broad to ask here as you can read in [ask]. I'd suggest asking the one that gave you the assignment.

Comment: Ok, I think I have cut away the not useful part. Do you know how to proceed through a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use tabulate, there is a solution to modify your code by:

1. Adding an extra row full of characters of specified size for each column at the end the array
2. Calling `tabulate` including specification of the alignment using `coalign`
3. Remove the extra row

Since the output is a string, the width of the columns is not associated with any measure e.g. in cm, so you will need to define a length scale that suits your needs, i.e. the number of characters per required width unit.

Note that 2 characters are removed from the computed width to account for the inner column margins which are 1 character left and right.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

pt = [(1,"Hydrogen","H",1.008), (2,"Helium","He",4.0026), (3, "Lithium", "Li", 6.94), (4, "Beryllium", "Be", 9.0122),
      (5, "Boron", "B", 10.81), (6, "Carbon", "C", 12.011), (7, "Nitrogen", "N", 14.007), (8, "Oxygen", "O", 15.999),
      (9, "Fluorine", "F", 18.998), (10, "Neon", "Ne", 20.180)]
head = ["No.", "Name", "Symbol", "Weight"]

lengthScale = 2
widths = [3, 20, 6, 10]
pt.append(["-"*(width*lengthScale-2) for width in widths])

tab = tabulate(pt, headers=head, tablefmt="grid", colalign=("right","left","center","right"))

for line in range(2):
    tab = tab[:tab.rfind('\n')]

print(tab)
```

It produces:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|   No. | Name                                   |   Symbol   |             Weight |
+=======+========================================+============+====================+
|     1 | Hydrogen                               |     H      |              1.008 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     2 | Helium                                 |     He     |             4.0026 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     3 | Lithium                                |     Li     |               6.94 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     4 | Beryllium                              |     Be     |             9.0122 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     5 | Boron                                  |     B      |              10.81 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     6 | Carbon                                 |     C      |             12.011 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     7 | Nitrogen                               |     N      |             14.007 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     8 | Oxygen                                 |     O      |             15.999 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|     9 | Fluorine                               |     F      |             18.998 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
|    10 | Neon                                   |     Ne     |              20.18 |
+-------+----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just wondering whether your answer include also the required alignment (right, left....). I am asking because of the suggest I was sent to use `for loop` and `rjust, center and ljust` functions to picture this table

Comment: It is included with the coalign parameter to tabulate

Comment: Thank you so much. If you could show me also a possible way to acomplish this through a `for loop and rjust, center and ljust`, just let me know.

Comment: Is there anyone then that could show a different solution with this method `for loop and rjust, center and ljust`?

Comment: You will not find someone that will write the code for you, this is not how stackoverflow works. You can try to write the code yourself and ask if you have a specific question. You can use two imbricated loops to go through each element (outer loop), then each element property (inner loop), and append these properties to a string with the desired formatting.